How to center JLabel & JTextArea in a horizontal box?
I have a Java Swing horizontal box that contains both a label and a JTextArea.
I am trying to center the label and text vertically within the box, but the text is showing up higher than the label.
I am trying to call " .setAlignmentY(Component.CENTER " on all three elements (box, label, text area), so I don't know why the label and text don't line up
How should I center the two vertically within their horizontal box?

Please show your current [mre] code, including and especially what layout manager your containers are using.

I'm not sure what you mean by "box", but you can center a JLabel and a JTextArea in a JPanel with a GridBagLayout.

[Edit] your question and post a screen capture of how your GUI looks and indicate which part of it is not what you want.

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, Creating a GUI With Swing.  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.
I went ahead and created the following GUI.

I used a JPanel with a FlowLayout.
Here's the complete runnable code.  A minimal reproducible example.
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CenterLabel implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CenterLabel());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Center Label");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createTextPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createTextPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Label:");
        panel.add(label);

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 30);
        textArea.setText("text");
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        panel.add(scrollPane);

        return panel;
    }

}


GroupLayout has a steep learning curve but it's what I default to
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

final class Test {

    private Test() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var label = new JLabel("JLabel");
        var textArea = new JTextArea("JTextArea");
        var panel = new JPanel(null);

        var layout = new GroupLayout(panel);

        var horizontalGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(label)
                .addComponent(textArea);

        var verticalGroup = layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.CENTER)
                .addComponent(label)
                .addComponent(textArea);

        layout.setHorizontalGroup(horizontalGroup);
        layout.setVerticalGroup(verticalGroup);

        panel.setLayout(layout);

        var frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

